# How can I support a stream image in the IconImageSource property of toolbarItems?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an image that converts to a stream and is added to the IconImageSource attribute of toolbar items.

** Facing issues **

Set the IconImageSource property in ToolbarItems to a stream ImageSource.
In Android, It raised issues like "Cannot access a closed stream, at System.IO.MemoryStream.get_Position()".

It does not display any image in toolbarItems on the iOS and UWP platforms.

I created two imageSource properties in the sample: OpenToolItem and CloseToolItem.

How can I assign stream value to OpenToolItem and CloseToolItem  Property in a my application?

Please refer the code below.

**My mainpage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local:TestingControl  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestStreamControl" 
                       xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                       x:Class="TestStreamControl.MainPage" OpenToolItem="https://aka.ms/campus.jpg" 
                       CloseToolItem="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-600w-1048185397.jpg">
</local:TestingControl>
```

**My mainpage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestStreamControl
{
    public partial class MainPage : TestingControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Stream openStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestStreamControl.Images.Meow2.jpg");
            var openSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => openStream);
            OpenToolItem = openSource;

            Stream closeStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestStreamControl.Images.lake_water_natural.jpg");
            var closeSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => closeStream);
            CloseToolItem = closeSource;
        }
    }
}
```

**TestingControl.cs**

namespace TestStreamControl
{

```
public partial class TestingControl : ContentPage
{
    private ToolbarItem ToolbarItemSource;
    public TestingControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddToolbarItem();
    }
    #region Bindable Property
    public static readonly BindableProperty OpenToolItemProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create(nameof(OpenToolItem), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(TestingControl), default(ImageSource), BindingMode.Default, null, OnPropertyChanged);

    public static readonly BindableProperty CloseToolItemProperty =
              BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CloseToolItem), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(TestingControl), default(ImageSource), BindingMode.Default, null, OnPropertyChanged);

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemStateProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemState), typeof(bool), typeof(TestingControl), false, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, OnItemStatePropertyChanged);
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    public ImageSource OpenToolItem
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(OpenToolItemProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(OpenToolItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource CloseToolItem
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(CloseToolItemProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CloseToolItemProperty, value); }
    }
    public bool ItemState
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ItemStateProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ItemStateProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Property changed events
    private static void OnPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        (bindable as TestingControl).OnSourcePropertyChanged(oldValue, newValue);
    }
    private static void OnItemStatePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        (bindable as TestingControl).OnSourcePropertyChanged(oldValue, newValue);
    }
    private void OnSourcePropertyChanged(object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        UpdateToolbar();
    }

    #endregion

    private void AddToolbarItem()
    {
        this.ToolbarItemSource = new ToolbarItem
        {
            Text = "Open",
            Priority = int.MaxValue,
            Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary,
            IconImageSource = this.GetToolbarItem()
        };
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(this.ToolbarItemSource);
        this.ToolbarItemSource.Clicked += OnToolbarItemClicked;
    }

    private void OnToolbarItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemState)
        {
           message.Text = "Message sent";
        }
        else
        {
           message.Text = "Message Received";
            
        }

        this.ItemState = !this.ItemState;
        UpdateToolbar();
    }

    private ImageSource GetToolbarItem()
    {

        var internalOpenIcon = OpenToolItem ?? (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP ? "https://aka.ms/campus.jpg" : "https://aka.ms/campus.jpg");
        var internalCloseIcon = CloseToolItem ?? (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP ? "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-600w-1048185397.jpg" : "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-600w-1048185397.jpg");
        return this.ItemState ? internalCloseIcon : internalOpenIcon;
    }
    private void UpdateToolbar()
    {

        if (this.ToolbarItemSource != null)
        {
            if (OpenToolItem != null || CloseToolItem != null)
            {
                this.ToolbarItemSource.Text = this.ItemState ? "Close" : "Open";
                this.ToolbarItemSource.IconImageSource = this.GetToolbarItem();
            }
            if (OpenToolItem == null && CloseToolItem == null)
            {
                this.ToolbarItemSource.Text = this.ItemState ? "Close" : "Open";
                this.ToolbarItemSource.IconImageSource = this.GetToolbarItem();
            }
            else
            {
                // this.ToolbarItemSource.Text = this.ItemState ? "Close" : "Open";
                this.ToolbarItemSource.IconImageSource = this.GetToolbarItem();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

}

**TestingControl.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestStreamControl.TestingControl">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" x:Name="message"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: how to connect stream image in IconImageSource . please Comment your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is these lines of code:

```cs
Stream openStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestStreamControl.Images.Meow2.jpg");
var openSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => openStream);
```

The `GetManifestResourceStream` is **before** the `Imagesource.FromStream()` call. That opens a stream, **one time**. (That stream is automatically closed at the end of the surrounding method, MainPage constructor. This later causes the error "Cannot access a closed stream".)

ImageSource requires code that will open the stream **each time** it is needed:

```cs
var openSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        Stream openStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestStreamControl.Images.Meow2.jpg");
        return openStream;
    });
```

The `GetManifestResourceStream` call is now **inside** the delegate code. That code gets called **each time** the ToolbarItem needs the stream.

Comment: Its work fine. how to add UriImageSource in OpenToolItem in IOS. In IOS uriImageSource values are not displayed in ToolBarItems

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. See if answers for [xamarinUriImageSource not working from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128252/xamarin-forms-image-source-not-working-from-url) help you. If not, create a new question, showing the exact code you are trying to use. [StackOverflow is designed to be helpful to others in the future; restricting each Q&A to ONE specific problem works best.] If that works on Android but not iOS, say that also.

Comment: If my answer solved your first problem (using GetManifestResourceSteam), please accept it as the answer, so people know that problem is solved.