# Xamarin.Forms ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im trying to display an image in xamarin forms from my local ASP.NET API.
I can reach the image on both pc and phone, but not in my custom android application. It also works in UWP.

I get the following error in output window: [0:] ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid: Uri: https://192.168.0.207:5001/images/festival/dourfestival.jpg

Im working in xamarin forms 5.0.0.2545

Things i have tried so far:

- changing httpclient implementation to Managed
- changing ssl/tls implementation to native TLS 1.2+
- reinstalling my application
- updating xamarin forms to latest stable version

This is my first time posting on here so, if this post lacks some info be sure to let me know, I will edit my post if needed.

```
XAML
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="270" Opacity="0.6"/>
```

Comment: can you load the image in the browser on the device/emulator?  Have you tested with a different image on the off chance that the first one has some sort of corruption?

Comment: Yeah i went to the Uri on my device and it perfectly loads in there, i was using online images before but now ive downloaded them (3 images, same ones), to host on my local API and they are not showing only on adroid application, UWP works fine.

Comment: I solved my issue by adding an URI to imageSource converter, I have used the answer of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128252/xamarin-forms-image-source-not-working-from-url
Thanks for the help though! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by adding an URI to imageSource converter, I have used the answer of this post [Xamarin Forms - Image source not working from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128252/xamarin-forms-image-source-not-working-from-url)

Converter

```
public class ImageSourceURIConverter : IValueConverter
{
    static WebClient Client = new WebClient();
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

        var byteArray = Client.DownloadData(value.ToString());
        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:ImageSourceURIConverter x:Key="ImageSourceURIConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ImageSourceURIConverter}}"
                                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                                       HeightRequest="270"
                                       Opacity="0.6"/>
```

Comment: For more information about [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks), you can refer to the official doc.